# influence of the number of variables on speed/memory allocation

Tags: matlab, variables

I have some ways to build my code, and its variables. for example, I can write:

```
for i=1:N
   Block(i,:,1)=circshift(baseRow1, [0 i-1]);
   Block(i,:,2)=circshift(baseRow2, [0 i-1]);
   Block(i,:,3)=circshift(baseRow3, [0 i-1]);
end
```

Which can be written also by:

```
for i=1:N
   Block1(i,:)=circshift(baseRow1, [0 i-1]);
   Block2(i,:)=circshift(baseRow2, [0 i-1]);
   Block3(i,:)=circshift(baseRow3, [0 i-1]);
end
```

Ignore what the function suppose to do, I ask about the best way to define the variables. In sense of speed/memory allocation- is there any difference? I should prefer less variables but larger, or many little variables?

In that example it may not matter, but it's a little piece from the whole code...
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking this out of plain curiosity or are you experiencing performance issues here?

Comment: How big is `N`? Unless it's pretty large, I wouldn't worry about this. If it is pretty large, then you can answer your question yourself by timing your code.

Comment: @Eitan T and Sam Roberts I have pretty big martices, and I  really write this program now, not just curiosity. In this part N=256, but those few rows build one little block from a big matrix. Because I going to use many times in those "Block" variables, i asked the question. It takes so much time to run it, so I prefer to know the answer before i try the two options... i can try to do it on this piece of code, but i don't know if it represents the whole code, that doing also other things...

Comment: @Adiel For starters I'd suggest storing all the `baseRow` matrices in one larger matrix, and invoking `circshift` once. This would save you the loop...

Comment: @EitanT it's a good idea, but will not save me the loop, because the loop is not over the different "baseRow" vectros, but over the length of each one of them. Each iteration doing another circ. on each vector and add it to a matrix. each vector become to be "circulant matrix"

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) - [Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DonKnuth). I agree with Eitan T on this one. Use a few "numbered" names as possible and rather exploit indexing as heavily as you can. It makes the handling of your data simpler.